# Xcode, Is there was to constrain in a circle?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm working with some Text views placed on top of some UIimages. Im wanting to shape them circular but I'm not sure if theres a way to constrain them that way in a way that would stay relatively the same on different phones.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! I think you can do something like this:

Each view is at a certain angle of the big circle. So you can constrain each view's x to the rightmost view x with a multiplier of cos(angle) and similarly constrain its y with a multiplier of sin(angle). You'll need to constrain the top and right views to the margins.

(In the image you don't have a rightmost view, maybe you can have a hidden view there.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!